# Commuting matrices and their Jordan forms

Tags: commutative-algebra, matrix-equations, jordan-normal-form, invariant-subspace, toeplitz-matrices

I am recently studying commuting matrices. I was reading the book Invariant Subspaces of Matrices with Applications(Godberg, Lancaster and Rodman) and pg.295-296 claims that a matrix $X$ is a solution to the equation $AX = XA$ if and only if $Z = S^{-1}XS$ is a solution to $JZ = ZJ$ where $J =S^{-1}AS$ is the Jordan form of $A$. Further, they claim that if $J = J_{m_1}(\lambda_1)  \oplus \cdots  \oplus J_{m_s}(\lambda_s)$, then $Z = S^{-1}XS = Y_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus Y_s$ where $Y_i$, $(i = 1,\cdots,s)$ is an upper triangular Toeplitz matrix. So I have this example and could not work the theorem on my example, and I am struggling understanding the theorem.

Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0.333 & 0 & 0 & 0.333 & 0.333 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\ 0 & 0.333 & 0.333 & 0 & 0 & 0.333
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then,

$$S = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1.667 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1.667 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0.75 & -1.5 & -20.7500 & -2 & 20 & -1 \\ 0.5 & 0 & -4.5 & -1 & 5 & -0.333 \\ 0.5 & 0 & 1.5 & 0 & -2 & -0.333
\end{bmatrix}$$ and

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.333 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0.333 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

What I know is that if I pick X in a way that $[(I \bigotimes A) - (A^T \bigotimes I)]vec(X) = 0$, $AX-XA = 0$ is satisfied, so for the A matrix I proceed with, I found A commutes with the following X matrix:

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -0.6325 & 0.6325 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -0.3162 & 0.3162 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

which then gives:

$$Z = S^{-1}XS = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2.6667 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0002 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.3162 & 0.0002 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

After this point, commutator becomes

$$JZ-ZJ = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.1741\times 10^{-3} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0222 \times 10^{-3}\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.1000\times 10^{-3} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Here's my question,

I used MATLAB for all my numerical computations, yet the $J$ and $Z$ seem to be almost commuting, rather then commuting, did I do something wrong or am I confused? I used linprog to find commuting matrices, in that case, I was able to find almost commuting pairs, yet the entries of the commutator was of order $10^{-12}$.

Also, I couldn't understand why my Z matrix is not a direct sum of upper triangular Toeplitz matrices. I am confused with the Theorem. Last thing is do $Z = S^{-1}XS$ imply that same matrix $S$ brings both $A$ and $X$ to their Jordan forms, in my case I doubt, but from a theoretical perspective, they supposed to be I guess.

Thanks, I appreciate any help or tip.

Comment: You have a sentence that begins "Further they claim ...". You should re-read what they actually say, surely there are restrictions - either that the $\lambda_i$ are different or that the $m_i$ are different. After all the conclusion would not be true if $A=I$. In your specific case you have two $1\times 1$ blocks $[1]$, so you'll get a lot of centraliser from that.

Comment: And just a comment: you do realise that it is trivial to see that if $A$ and $X$ commute, then  $S^{-1}AS$  and $S^{-1}XS$ commute?

Comment: Finally: you have a sentence "Last thing is do ..". I can't quite follow. But you seen to say that $S$ brings both $A$ and $X$ to their Jordan forms: that's not so. It transforms $A$ to its JCF because that's how we chose it, but $X$ need not go to its JCF - again, think of case $A=S=I$ and $X$ can be arbitrary, not necessarily in JCF. Even in the special case where the theorem you quote is true, $S^{-1}XS$ will be Toeplitz, not necessarily Jordan.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I couldn't see a note about what you said in you first comment but as I read on the book & your comments, I get the idea better.

Answer (score 1):

First, the statement "if $J = J_{m_1}(\lambda_1)  \oplus \cdots  \oplus J_{m_s}(\lambda_s)$ then $Z = S^{-1}XS = Y_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus Y_s$ where $Y_i$, $(i = 1,\cdots,s)$ is an upper triangular Toeplitz matrix." is true only when the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_s$ are *distinct*.  If $J$ has a repeated eigenvalue, this characterization of the centralizer is incomplete.

Second, I checked your calculations with rational numbers in Sympy for precision.  I get
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 &
 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$S=\left[\begin{matrix}-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\\-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 2\\
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2\\0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -6 & 1\\1 & 0 & -3 & \frac{1}{2} & 0
& 0\\1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$J=S^{-1} A S = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & \frac{1}{3} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0
& 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0
& \frac{1}{2} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$X=\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 &
0 & 0 & 0\\- \frac{253}{400} & \frac{253}{400} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\- \frac{253}{8
00} & \frac{253}{800} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right
]$$
$$AX-XA = 0$$
$$Z=S^{-1}X S=\left[\begin{matrix}3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 &
 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{253}{800} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\3 & 0
& 0 & 0 & 0 & -2\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$J Z- Z J = 0$$
Which seems fine to me (the blocks belonging to distinct eigenvalues have Toeplitz form.  The blocks for a repeated eigenvalue don't.)

Comment: Thank you very much, my main confusion arised from Matlab, thanks for your effort, I really appreciate!